# Implement ASN.1 description

Tags: java, c, asn.1

I wrote this ASN.1 description

```
Demo-module DEFINITIONS ::=       -- Module-name DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

BEGIN

ClientFirstRequest ::= SEQUENCE {                  
   clientInt     INTEGER
}        

ServerFirstResponse ::= SEQUENCE {                
   serverInt    INTEGER ,        
   serverString     IA5String  
 }  

ClientSecondRequest ::= SEQUENCE {                  
   clientString     IA5String
}    

ServerSecondResponse ::= SEQUENCE {                
   serverResponse     IA5String
}  



END                                      -- end of module, END required
```

I have a code who send an integer to a server , it work perfectly

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
 dos.writeInt(4);
```

But I  tried to use the ASN.1 classes and i have a problem, I tried the following code, but I have an error in the setValue method

```
ClientFirstRequest h = new ClientFirstRequest();
        h.setValue(4);
        BerOutputStream bos = new BerOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
         h.encode(bos);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a question you should ask the vendor of the ASN.1 Tool you are using.  Each ASN.1 Tool has its own way of going from your values to the encoded byte stream even though the resulting byte stream should be the same for all ASN.1 tools.  You have not indicated which ASN.1 Tools you are using.